# How to select properties that are not in groupby

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select some properties that are not in my `group by`. Is this possible?

```
var r = from w in drinks.ToList()
  group w by new{
   w.DrinkId
  } into wGroup
  select new DrinksValue(){
   DrinkId = wGroup.DrinkId,
   CatId = // trying to pull from wGroup???
   Lasting = // trying to pull from wGroup???
   DrinkTypes = wGroup.Select( x => new DrinkAttributes { Taste = wGroup.Key.Flavor, Benefit = wGroup.Sum(x => x.Value)
  }).ToList()
};
```

How would I get CatId, and Lasting properties from the `drinks.ToList()`?

If I add them to the group like `w.DrinkId, w.Flavor, w.Value, w.CatId, w.Lasting` it messes up my results.

I can get other properties like `Value` using `.Sum` , but these properties aren't computed values.

Example of data:

```
DrinkId | CatId | Lasting | Flavor | Value
------------------------------------------
1     2        5.1      orange   11.0
1     2        5.1      blue     09.0
1     2        6.0      red      10.0
2     3        6.0      red      10.0
2     3        6.0      yellow   01.0
```

Want the results to be grouped like this:

```
{
  "DrinkId": 1,
  "CatId": 2,
  "Lasting": 5.1,
  "DrinkTypes": [{ Taste: orange,  Benefit: 11.0}, {Taste: blue,  Benefit: 09.0}, {Taste: red,  Benefit: 10.0}]
}
```

Comment: Suppose a group has more than one `CatId` or `Lasting`. Which one do you want?

Comment: @DStanley thanks, I'm not sure what you mean?  I'll put example of the data I'm using in the question.

Comment: The question is unclear, you want those properties but you don't tell us which one you want or what types are CatId and Lasting. If theres only one in each group, you can add them to the `GroupBy`, if there are 0 or multiple you need to say if you want only one or a list, if only one which one.

Comment: You say grouping by `w.DrinkId, w.CatId, w.Lasting` gives you wrong results, I'm guessing because for one `DrinkId` there can be multiple `CatId` or `Lasting` values. So which of those multiple values would you want in the output?

Comment: @DStanley I added example of data in question. So any of the properties that I want to select need to be in the groupby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work:

```cs
var query = 
    from w in drinks
    group w by new { w.DrinkId, w.CatId, w.Lasting } into wGroup
    select new DrinksValue
    {
        DrinkId = wGroup.Key.DrinkId,
        CatId = wGroup.Key.CatId,
        Lasting = wGroup.Key.Lasting,
        DrinkTypes = wGroup.Select(x => new DrinkAttributes 
            { Taste = x.Flavor, Benefit = x.Value }
            ).ToList()          
    }
};

var r = query.ToList()
```